# Trying to use a mid 2011 iMac as a display screen for my 2016 MacBookPro

Tags: display, imac

I have the two computers connected with the Thunderbolt cord. But when I hit F2 on the 2011 iMac, nothing happens. Well I shouldn't say nothing happens, the screen flashes as if I were taking a screen grab.

I am using the Thunderbolt Cable, connected by the Thunderbolt 3 USC-C to Tunderbolt 2 Adapter, but am not having any luck.

The 2011 is running on El Capitan and the MacBook is running on Mojave.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) you have to press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to enter target display mode, not just <kbd>F2</kbd>.